# Spring Bean with Abstract classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I wanted to know how Spring DI works with Abstract classes.
For example take look at below two samples:

Dao layer:

```
  public abstract class BaseDaoImpl<T extends ShoppingCartEntity> implements BaseDao<T> {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public BaseDaoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
      super();
      this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

   //common dao layer methods like getAll(),save(entity) etc
  }
```

I haven't marked BaseDaoImpl with `@Repository("baseDao")` annotation but still it was able inject the `@Autowired` dependency on sessionFactory instance.

Service layer:

```
@Service("baseService")
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl implements Serializable {

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Autowired
  private DaoProvider daoProvider;
  //other fields
  }
```

Here I have marked the BaseService as abstract and also `@Service` annotation is used which will register the BaseService  class as Spring Bean component for service layer.

Now,I have two questions:

1. **If a class is abstract then How does Spring create a bean from it?**
2. **If a class is not marked with any spring bean component
   annotation(like `@Component,@Repository,@Service or @Conroller`)
   should we be able to Autowired dependencies on these
   classes?**(like my daoLayer base class which is not a spring bean
   component but still I'm able to inject

   `@Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;`

Comment: You have an `abstract` class named `BaseDaoImpl`. This is incredibly confusing.

Comment: It contains common getter methods(like save(entity),getAll() etc) which can be reused in other inheriting sub classes.

Comment: I am talking about the _name_ of the class.

Comment: whats the confusion?BaseDao is interface and BaseDaoImpl is its corresponding implementation class.

Comment: But it is `abstract` and prefixed with `Base` it should not be suffixed with `Impl` since it must be extended.

Comment: Ok I got it.thats allright.But can you provide any suitable explanation of my question?I am interested to know the spring behaviour that is internally taking place here

Comment: I believe that it reflects on your package and if it can locate a concrete subclass that it can instantiate it will use that subclass automatically. As for `Autowired` I imagine it has nothing to do with `Repository` or `Controller` or whatever because if it required those annotations then it would be unable to automatically inject dependencies in other contexts. Also I thought `Autowired` was an implementation of a standardized Java `Inject` annotation that is independent from Spring.

Comment: Also, please don't name interfaces `BaseXyz`